# compare list of strings with another string

Tags: c#, linq

I have 1 long string which looks like :`"item1, item7, item9"` etc.
Then I have a list which looks like:

```
"item2",
"item3",
"item9"
```

I want to run a check to see if any of the list strings match anything within the long string.  I could use a foreach loop, but I'm thinking there must be an easy LINQ expression which I can't seem to get right.

Comment: You say "I can't seem to get right". Often showing your attempts is revealing of your real intent (eg do you really just care that there is a match, or do you want to know the value of the strings that match)

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
var isContained = list.Any(x=>stringValue.Contains(x));
```

where `list` is the list of strings, `stringValue` is the string you have.

In the above code, we use the `Any` method, which looks if there is any element in the list that makes the predicate we supply to be `true`. The predicate has as input a list item and check if this item is contained in the `stringValue`. If so that returns true. Otherwise false.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string longString = "item1,item7,item9";
        List<string> myList=new List<string>(new string[]{"item2","item3","item9"});

        if (myList.Any(str => longString.Contains(str)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("success!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fail!");
        }
```

Comment: What does the string.Format add?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
// Set up the example data
String searchIn = "item1, item7, item9";
List<String> searchFor = new List<String>();
searchFor.Add("item2");
searchFor.Add("item3");
searchFor.Add("item9");

var firstMatch = searchFor.FirstOrDefault(p => { return -1 != searchIn.IndexOf(p); });
// firstMatch will contain null if no item from searchFor was found in searchIn,
// otherwise it will be a reference to the first item that was found.
```

Comment: You're welcome.  I upvoted the accepted solution, because it more faithfully answers the question by providing a "check" and uses the `String.Contains(string)` method, which is a better choice than mine.